# Docker Jupyter image not exposing port

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, docker-image

I have created Jupyter docker image using alpine linux. Everything is working fine, but container is not exposing the port. But inside the container the port is working. But I cannot access from my host machine.

I have written image file as shown below:

```
FROM vanarajaz/alpine-python

MAINTAINER Vanaraj C "vanaraj@assistanz.com

"RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \

python3 -m pip install jupyter

EXPOSE 8888

CMD [ "jupyter", "notebook" ]
```

After creating the container, I got the below error:

```
[I 13:32:34.019 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret[C 13:32:34.592 NotebookApp] Running as root is not recommended. Use --allow-root to bypass.From:Vanaraj
[I 13:32:34.019 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret[C 13:32:34.592 NotebookApp] Running as root is not recommended. Use --allow-root to bypass.
```

I don't know how to fix this error. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: run with `docker run -d -p 8888:8888 imagename`, to solve the error you need to change the USER in your Dockerfile which is starting the service: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user . Default this is root but this is not secure, give your file owners/permissions and run with a different user.

Comment: Thanks lvthillo... Working fine now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`EXPOSE` is documentation between the person building the image and the person running the container. See [docker's documentation for more details](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose). It does not impact the ability to publish the port, and doesn't automatically publish the port for you.

To publish the port if you want to access it from your host, use `docker run -p`, or a `ports` section of your compose yml file.

Or if you want to communicate from container to container, there's no need to publish the port. All you need for that is both containers to be on the same docker network.